# Koltin Function References : This expression is unused

Tags: android, kotlin

When I use Kotlin function expression as follows, I get a warning that the expression is unused from the compiler.

```
        val button: Button by lazy{findViewById(R.id.button)}
        nextButton.setOnClickListener { viewModel::callFoo }
```

The warning goes away, when I call the actual function from within the lambda.

```
        val button: Button by lazy{findViewById(R.id.button)}
        nextButton.setOnClickListener { viewModel.callFoo() }
```

Looking at the docs for function references don't really provide any light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler is correct, your first code does nothing. You can check this by yourself, `callFoo()` won't be invoked.

This code is like saying: "When clicked, run my lambda `{ viewModel::callFoo }` which does really nothing". It just acquires a function reference and doesn't do anything with it. What you meant is to pass a function reference to `setOnClickListener()` instead of your lambda:

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(viewModel::callFoo)
```